# Is the use of label and radio button as CSS hook proper HTML?

Tags: html, css, input, label, accessibility

For CSS, the combination of `<label />` and `<input type="radio" />` is a blessing - it allows commanding elements back through the DOM with no need for javascript, with all sorts of useful applications. Example:

```
<style>
#wrapper {width:300px; height:200px; text-align:center;}
.slide {position:relative; width:300px; height:200px; line-height:200px; border:1px solid black; font-size:3em; color:crimson;}
input {display:none;}
input[name="ito"] + .slide {display:none;}
input[name="ito"]:checked + .slide {display:block;}
.slide label {position:absolute; top:0; color:black;}
.slide label:first-of-type {left:0;}
.slide label:last-of-type {right:0;}
#is:checked ~ [for="is"], #this:checked ~ [for="this"], #ok:checked ~ [for="ok"] {color:crimson;}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <input name="ito" type="radio" id="is" checked>
  <div class="slide">IS
    <label for="ok">«</label><label for="this">»</label>
  </div>
    <input name="ito" type="radio" id="this">
  <div class="slide">THIS
    <label for="is">«</label><label for="ok">»</label>
  </div>
    <input name="ito" type="radio" id="ok">
  <div class="slide">OK?
    <label for="this">«</label><label for="is">»</label>
  </div>
    <label for="is">1</label><label for="this">2</label><label for="ok">3</label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v6eeqxog/

The code is technically valid as per https://html5.validator.nu, but how properly is it used?

I mean, there is some obvious level of clutter in the code, but going beyond that - is this ok for accessibility or other such concerns?

Comment: I think this is some of those "browser hacks" used to obtain a particular behavior. There are many hacks, they are not wrong, there is no morality in compiling code. Either it works or it does not. Unless it works cross browser I see no problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn’t seem to be keyboard-accessible. You can’t focus the radio button (with the Tab key) to switch the "slides" (with the Arrow keys). It works without this CSS because then you can focus the radio buttons.

See WCAG 2.0 guideline 2.1: [Keyboard Accessible: Make all functionality available from a keyboard.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#keyboard-operation)

Comment: Great to know, thanks. But how about the js/jquery counterparts, do you happen to know if they solve this issue or not?